# 'The Type or namespace name 'T4MVC_MyController' does not exists in the namespace 'MyProject.Controllers.My' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: rebuild, t4mvc

I just cloned an new project, started the npm and when I rebuild I got several similiar errors, in the error list like the following:

[image]

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Unload all the projects in the solution except the web application project.
2. Clean the solution and rebuild the solution again (make sure you have the npm started before)
3. Make sure the solution will rebuild successfully.
4. Reload again all the solution projects.
5. Rebuild again the solution.